# SilliCompressor is throwing Number Format Exception For input String: Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, numberformatexception

Hey I am using sillicompressor for compressing images and now the problem is that it is throwing numberformatException. I tried everything but nothing is working. Please guide me how can i solve this problem.

**CODE IS HERE**

```
  activityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(), new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {


        if (result.getResultCode() == RESULT_OK && null != result.getData()) {

            if (result.getData().getClipData() != null) {
                int countofImages = result.getData().getClipData().getItemCount();


                    //this part is to select multiple images
                    for (int i = 0; i < countofImages; i++) {

                        if (imageList.size() < 8)
                        {
                             imageuri = result.getData().getClipData().getItemAt(i).getUri();

                            File file = new File(SiliCompressor.with(getContext()).compress(FileUtils.getPath(getContext(), imageuri), new File(getContext().getCacheDir(), "temp" + i)));
                            compresseduri = Uri.fromFile(file);


                            imageList.add(new CustomModel(getfilename(imageuri), compresseduri));
                        } else
                            {
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Can't select more than 8 images", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                    //then notify the adapter
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                rentSell3Binding.totalphotos.setText("Photos (" + imageList.size() + ")");

                }
                //this part is to select single image
                else {
                if (imageList.size()<8) {
                     imageuri = result.getData().getData();

                    File file = new File(SiliCompressor.with(getContext()).compress(FileUtils.getPath(getContext(), imageuri), new File(getContext().getCacheDir(), "temp")));

                    compresseduri = Uri.fromFile(file);

                    imageList.add(new CustomModel(getfilename(imageuri), compresseduri));

                }else
                {

                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Can't select more than 8 images", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

                //notify the adapter
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                rentSell3Binding.totalphotos.setText("Photos (" + imageList.size() + ")");

                }
        }
```

**Error is throwing on this line**

```
File file = new File(SiliCompressor.with(getContext()).compress(FileUtils.getPath(getContext(), imageuri), new File(getContext().getCacheDir(), "temp" + i)));
```

**StackTrace**

```
  java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "msf:126968"
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:594)
    at java.lang.Long.valueOf(Long.java:808)
    at com.iceteck.silicompressorr.FileUtils.getPath(FileUtils.java:288)
    at com.shrihari.backsoon.Listing_Fragment_3$5.onActivityResult(Listing_Fragment_3.java:263)
```

Comment: "it is throwing numberformatException" -- please edit your question and post the entire stack trace.

Comment: please check i have added the stack trace

Comment: `FileUtils.getPath(getContext(), imageuri)` -- delete `FileUtils.getPath()`, and please never use it again. A `Uri` is not a file. Based on the limited documentation, it looks like you can simply replace `FileUtils.getPath(getContext(), imageuri)` with `imageuri.toString()`.

Comment: actually this same code is working fine on the emulator sir but it is showing the problem here on the physical device

Comment: and i tried your suggested thing but it is not working